# Which countries do not require visas for Brazilian travelers

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, brazilian-citizens

Which countries do not require visas for Brazilian travelers ?

- If exist what is the maximum number of days of stay in country?

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia actually has up-to-date pages that answer this question with colour-coded maps and tables, for every citizenship of the world. All the information is backed by official references.

The page for Brazilian citizens is [Visa requirements for Brazilian citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Brazilian_citizens).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The **Mercosul** countries do not require passport, only RG (Identity card) with a recent photo.

> Note: Usually the maximum period is 90 days.
>
> Source in portuguese: [Correio Brasiliense](http://www.correiobraziliense.com.br/app/noticia/turismo/2013/01/02/interna_turismo,342095/confira-a-lista-de-paises-que-nao-exigem-visto-de-turistas-brasileiros.shtml)

- South Africa
- Germany
- Andorra
- French West Indies
- Argentina
- Austria
- Bahamas
- Barbados
- Belgium
- Bolivia
- Bosnia Guyana
- Bulgaria
- Chile
- Colombia
- South Korea
- Costa Rica
- Croatia
- Denmark
- Ecuador
- Slovakia
- Slovenia
- Spain
- Philippines
- Finland
- France
- Greece
- Guatemala
- Honduras
- Holland
- Hong Kong
- Hungary
- Ireland
- Iceland
- Israel
- Italy
- Liechtenstein
- Luxembourg
- Malaysia
- Morocco
- Mexico
- Monaco
- Namibia
- Norway
- New Zealand
- Panama
- Paraguay
- Peru
- Poland
- Portugal
- United Kingdom
- Czech republic
- Romania
- Russia
- San Marino
- Serbia
- Sweden
- Switzerland
- Suriname
- Thailand
- Trinidad and Tobago
- Tunisia
- Turkey
- Ukraine
- Uruguay
- Vatican
- Venezuela